# Greatest number in fibonacci sequence with property: sum of digits=index in fibonacci sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers

I came across very interesting sequence based on fibonacci sequence. From fibonacci numbers we choose only elements with digit sum=index in fibonacci sequence. It is very interesting that we most probably know the greatest number with that property. How come we can say probably I understand that sequence is growing very quickly, but what is the idea of probably knowing the greatest number. How did mathematicans conclude that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote [this](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibmaths.html#section1.2) webpage, which further quotes Robert Dawson:

> Robert Dawson of Saint Mary's University, Nova Scotia, Canada summarises a simple statistical argument (originally in the article referred to below by David Terr) that suggests there may be only a finite number (in fact, just 20 numbers) in this series:
>
> > "The number of decimal digits in Fib(N) can be shown to be about 0.2
> >     N, and the average value of a decimal digit is (0+1+...+8+9)/10 = 4·5.
> >     Thus, unless the digits of Fibonacci numbers have some so-far
> >     undiscovered pattern, we would expect the digit sum to be about 0.9 N.
> >     This falls further behind N as N gets larger. Fib(2222) (with 465
> >     digits) is the largest known Fibonacci number with this property.
> >     There are no others with N<5000, and it seems likely that Fib(2222) is
> >     actually the largest one. However, no proof exists!"